# SetImageBitmap shows white blank full screen

Tags: android

I have a CardActivity that opens a CameraActivity. I have an imagebutton I press and then the native camera app opens and I can take a picture. I try to pass that back to my CardActivity using an intent with a ByteArray. But it gives me a blank white screen. It doesnt insert anything into the imageview. The Bitmap element is not null, it has something.

This is my switch for starting the camera activity and setting image:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.pButton1:
                    Intent cam = new Intent(CardActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                    startActivity(cam);
                    returnImage2();
                    mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    mImageView.setRotation(180);
                    break;
```

This is my returnImage2();

```
public void returnImage2() {

        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.openFileInput("myImage"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is my cameraActivity:

```
    public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
        private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
        private ImageView mImageView;
        private Bitmap mImageBitmap;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
        public void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    System.out.println("ERR CANNOT CREATE FILE");
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                            "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                            photoFile);
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                }
            }
        }
        private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            // Create an image file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            File image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    storageDir      /* directory */
            );

            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
            return image;
        }
        private File createImageFile2() throws IOException {
            // Create an image file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            File image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    storageDir      /* directory */
            );

            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
            return image;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    mImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
                    cImageFromBitmap(mImageBitmap);
                    //mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    //mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
                    //mImageView.setRotation(180);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        public String cImageFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
            String fileName = "myImage";//no .png or .jpg needed
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                // remember close file output
                fo.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                fileName = null;
            }
            return fileName;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using `REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO` for starting your activity

```
             startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO)
```

but you are checking for `REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE` on `onActivityResult`

```
             if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
```

ALSO:

I don't know why you are going through all this work to create a file.  When you use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` the bitmap itself comes back in the result intent:

```
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Comment: The reason I go through all of this work is to handle over 1 mb intents :/ I still get the white screen if I remove that part of the if check